# How to add a UILabel as a subview of UIButton iOS

Tags: ios, uibutton, uilabel, subview

I want to add a `UILabel` within a `UIButton`. 
Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[self addressSearch] setDelegate:self];
    [[self worldMap] setDelegate:self];

    self.boolPushButtonTapped = YES;
    self.addressSearch.barStyle = 1;

    //Create pushButton
    self.pushButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    self.pushButton.frame = CGRectMake(106, 436, 110, 59);

    [self.pushButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pushButton2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.pushButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pushButtonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    //Label
    self.distanceLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    self.distanceLabel.text = @"test";

    [self.pushButton addSubview:self.distanceLabel];


    [self.view addSubview:self.pushButton];
}
```

If I don't use `alloc` `init` I receive an error and if I use the text in that label does not change.
Error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[NSLayoutConstraint constant], /SourceCache/Foundation/Foundation-992/Layout.subproj/NSLayoutConstraint.m:560
2012-10-01 14:01:01.889 RemindMe[1116:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '(null)'
```

I want to add inside this button because there is an animation.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to set the text of a button or set up a UILabel instance inside the frame of a UIButton?

Comment: Set a UILabel instance inside the UIButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
[self.pushButton.titleLabel setText: @"anytext"];
```

Updated answer:

As mentioned in the [UIButton Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html), you should set the title using `setTitle:forState:`.

Then the formatting can be done in the button's associated label object `titleLabel`.

So you need not add another UILabel.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I reckon this is the simplest way. There is no need to create a UILabel in my case.

Comment: This actually causes issues with the titleLabel's sizing and can truncate the text. The correct way to set the button's title is with [self.pushButton setTitle:@"anytext" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; This will properly resize the button's label to fit the new title.

Answer (score 1):

UIButtons now give you a lot of control, but before some things like custom fonts were possible I just made a simple control that had a UIButton and UILabel. I would just put the UILabel on top of the UIButton with a small 2px or so padding.

Comment: but doing that I would have to animate the UILabel and the UIButton, right?

Comment: Sorry, missed the animation part. There are ways to make it work, but if you just need text with no fancy formatting or anything, use the code listed by KarenAnne.